# ASP.NET C#, Access div element from nested Listview Code Behind

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to get the (div id="imgGallery" runat="server") element from nested Listview to modify the class name programatically.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1" onitemdatabound="ListView1_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="VersionId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("VersionId") %>' Visible="false" />
    <asp:Label ID="MenuContent" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ContentText") %>' />
    <br />
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder2">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div id="imgGallery" class="images" runat="server">
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>' runat="server" ToolTip="Text" />
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder2"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</ItemTemplate>
<LayoutTemplate>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemSeparatorTemplate>
    <br />
    <hr />
    <br />
</ItemSeparatorTemplate>
```

on my code behind I tried the code below which doesn't work... and I tried different ways but can't find solution.

```
    ListView listView2 = (ListView)ListView1.FindControl("ListView2");
HtmlGenericControl mydiv = (HtmlGenericControl)listView2.FindControl("imgGallery");
mydiv.Attributes.Clear();
```

Comment: On which event you are trying to find that div ??

Comment: The ListView is inside a tab, when I move from tab0 to tab1 I need to remove the class attribute from div element.

Comment: I can do it without listview.

Answer (score 1):

You sholuld work with inner element of databound controls on databinding stage or iterating through row collection (called databind method before)

Comment: The template'ed controls in the ASP.NET markup can be accessed after their `Init` event, which is called when the template (and thus the markup) is "instantiated". It doesn't directly align with data-binding (but it *could* be the result of it), but is a useful concept nevertheless ..

Comment: So that's the only way? there's no way to get the div element directly?

Comment: @user1567683 See my comment about `Init` (of controls inside..)

Comment: I'm sorry pst, I'm very new at this (I started 2 months ago). Do you know a link or could you give me a sample? I really appreciate that you reply

Comment: i use only that way. And cann't figure it out how to get access to template markup object without creating custom control inherited to ListView. Maybe Pst will provide a bit of code.